# Can we add a new close reason?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Inspired by [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/17596/437) and [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17293/what-is-a-greenfield-project-in-it), can we add the following close reason?

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is a question in search of an objective definition; not a question seeking answers backed up by experience, reason, and/or logic. Google is your friend.

**EDIT:** Related - [What if a question asks for a definition that is easily found via a Search or in Wikipedia?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2221/437)

Comment: Although I might omit or rephrase the "Google is your friend" part, I agree with your sentiment.

Comment: I have discussed this in the workplace chat and IIRC it was found to be pretty stupid for a Q&A site to tell its users to go search for answers elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Logic is not an acceptable way to back up an answer.  Logic can be flawed.

Instead perhaps when some what asks what a term means a well written answer with links to sites that back up the description, as well as examples of how the person writing the answer has experienced the term in the workplace would be much better.

So in short these types of questions should be very much on topic and are the bread and butter of a Q&A Site.  **We should never be suggesting to our users that they go somewhere else to learn about navigating the workplace.**  And part of that is understanding the terminology used in the workplace.

That said we should not address specific acronyms as many different places have their own acronyms which mean different things.

Comment: How about if the answer only uses "non-flawed logic"?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - The use of logic in a question is fine but it should still be backed up with references and/or experience.  This topic is generally so broad and there are so many variables that it is basically effectively to take them all in and cover all the bases logic wise.  There is also the variablity of flawed criteria.  If I were to tell you that 1+1 = 10 you would logically conclude that I was using base 2... but maybe I just really suck at math